# How can I go back to the first view from the third view directly?

Tags: iphone

When I touch cancel button in the third view, I want to go back to the first view directly. How can I do that?

This is the code.

```
// this part is in the first view.
SecondController *aSecondController = [[SecondController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *aNaviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aSecondController];
self.naviController = aNaviController;
[aNaviController release];
[aSecondController release];
[self.view addSubview:naviController.view];

// this part is in the second view.
ThirdController *thirdController = [[ThirdController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];             
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdView];
[thirdView release];

// this part is in the third view.
- (void)cancel {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // this only goes to the second view.
}
```

popToViewController, popToRootViewController only go to the second view also.

Comment: Sorry, I initially did not notice the difference.  I gave your question an up-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the navigation controller in your app delegate. Make the first view controller the nav controller's root controller instead of having the first view controller own the nav controller. Then you can use `-popToRootViewController:animated:` as the other answers have suggested.

Comment: You clearly know how to set up the nav controller; you're already doing it. Move that code to someplace in your app delegate, such as `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Get rid of the `naviController` property in your first view controller. Instead of specifying the second view controller for your nav controller's root, specify the first view controller. Which part of this is confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **popToRootViewController:animated:** method, if your root view controller is the one you're after.  You can also use **popToViewController:animated:** to specify which controller you want to end up with on the top of the navigation stack.

Comment: Does it go to the first view? Why is navigation bar still there?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UINavigationController`s](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

```
- (void)cancel {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

And if you ever want to pop to a specific view controller you can use `popToViewController:animated:` and use the `viewControllers` property to get the view controller at the correct index.

Comment: Does it go to the first view? Why is navigation bar still there?

Comment: Because it goes to the first view in the view controller, and you are double posting.. dont do that. Look at the `setNavigationBarHidden:` method.